# Разница между var и const

Tags: freepascal

Решил выучить Паскаль (При помощи книги, "Песни о Паскале").

Но я так и не понял отличие var от const

Можете объяснить?

Comment: забавно, вы нашли трудность там, где ее просто нет)

Comment: кстати, как у вас с английским? `const` — от слова _constant_ (постоянный), `var` — от слова _variable_ (переменный).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В блоке var объявляются *переменные* - именованные области памяти, значения которых можно изменить в любой момент. В блоке const объявляются *константы* - именованные области памяти, значение которых устанавливается один раз и не может быть изменено. Если ваш учебник вам этого не объяснил, выкиньте его на помойку и возьмите другой. Фаронова, например. Подобные вещи объясняются в самом начале любого приличного учебника.

Comment: Мм, Фаронов...)